# Laravel How to define a file location on .env?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `.json` file that I want to define on `.env`.
How do I do that ?
my json file is on `(laravel root folder)/json_google/api_key.json` .
I tried `GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION=/json_google/api_key.json` but doesn't work ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use .env variable using constants file.

```
.env file

GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION=/json_google/api_key.json
```

Now in config/constatns.php set

```
return [
       'STORAGE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION' => env("GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION", ""),
];
```

Fetch json file path

```
Config::get('constants.STORAGE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION')
```

Comment: Whats the benefit of adding this to constants and using `Config::get('constants.STORAGE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION')` over just `env('GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION')` ?

Comment: You can use either config/app.php or config/constants.php file for use .env variable. Laravel recommends only to use env() within the config files.  [Checkout laravel environment configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: I see. Fetching all settings via Config makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

Laravel has many helper functions to resolve the path. Such as base_path() in your case. You'll find all helpers here: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`

```
base_path(env('GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION');
```

However, I'd set the full path instead of a relative path. Otherwise your application has to know what it should be relative to (laravel root, or app path, ...) and take this into account, which kind of defeats the purpose of putting the file location outside your code base, as it makes it harder to move it to some place else.

As the .env file is per deployment, there is no problem with setting the full path.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. base_path is a laravel helper function that returns the path to the app root. So in my .env file I have: GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILENAME=gcs_credentials.json then in my config/filesystems.php I have 'key_file' => base_path(env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILENAME'))